# OS X How do I update relative date display when date changes?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdateformatter

My application stores the date & time of the last data update using the defaults system.

My window has a text box that is bound to the value. This text box also has a date formatter attached. All done through Interface Builder. The date format is set to use relative dates.

Data only updates during the day and each time a new piece of data arrives the text field updates perfectly. So I get something like:

Today, 09:30
Today, 09:35
Today, 09:40
…
Today, 17:40

17:40 will be the last data update for the day.

The problem is that once it turns midnight it will still say Today, 17:40, when it should say Yesterday, 17:40.

If I quit and reopen the application then it displays Yesterday, 17:40.

I think I need to tell something to refresh but I'm not sure what and I can't find an example.

1) Apparently you can send fake willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey notifications but many people say this is not correct.

2) I've tried setting the user defaults value to itself after midnight but this didn't trigger the change.

3) I've tried setting the user defaults value to nil then back after midnight but this didn't work either.

I'm sure there's a correct and simple way to do this but I can't find it.

What do I need to trigger?
Which object do I need to trigger on?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update that display using a timer... Do something like this:

(in your viewDidLoad, probably)

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(refreshDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

... then you just build a new method which refreshes your time field

```
- (void)refreshDisplay {
    // do something to refresh your text label based on relative date
}
```

Comment: I've got the NSTimer working well - fires everyday at midnight (and updates some other things). I have a similar method (midnightUpdates) like you suggest. What I'm still not sure of is what to call to do the actual refresh?

Comment: Do you have an outlet set up for your text box? Maybe a `[yourTextbox setNeedsDisplay]` would do the trick.

Comment: I've done some more investigation and after midnight the value changes automatically but doesn't call a display on the NSTextField automatically. It's only updated the next time something happens to redisplay - such as the window being activated.

So you're right @James Boucher - if you want the change to be reflected in the UI immediately then you have to do [yourTextBox display]. It's the NSTextField that needs to do something - there's no need to send a KVO update or change the NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Apparently you can send fake willChangeValueForKey and
>   didChangeValueForKey notifications but many people say this is not
>   correct.

I would say you can use this way. Nothing bad in this way.